# find value in several dictionaries

Tags: python

first you have only one dictionary,everything's fine with

```
def getNPCName(self,ID):
    return self.npcs[ID].name
```

then,got another dictionary,the code become this

```
def getNPCName(self,ID):
    for x in (self.npcs,self.deadnpcs):
        if ID in x:
            return x[ID].name 
    return ''
```

i don't think this would be a good practice.

there should be some dictionary already exists, they union several dictionaries,not really merge them, but act just like one dictionary for some apis.

```
self.allnpclist = some_kind_of_dictionary(self.alive,self.dead)
```

my code should be this

```
def getNPCName(self,ID):
    return self.allnpclist[ID].name
```

i think i shouldn't write it by myself

Comment: I think you should use one dictionary for all npcs, while add a status code of "is_alive" so there's no need of searching cross dicts?

Comment: How do you propose the union deals with duplicate keys?

Answer (score 0):

A general solution I can think about:

```
npcs={...}
deadnpcs={...}
undeadnpcs={...}
npc_dicts={'npcs':npcs,'deadnpcs':deadnpcs,...}

def getNPCName(ID):
    for one in npc_dicts:
        choosen_one=getattr(npc_dicts[one],ID,None)
        if choosen_one:
            return choosen_one.name
```

Comment: Because dictionaries have no ordering, results for any keys duplicated across dictionaries are going to result in a random value being returned for that key. It may work for the specific case of the OP where there are not supposed to be duplicate keys, but for the generic case you'll need to handle this explicitly. Either specify an ordering (so use a list for `npc_dicts` instead) or merge the values for all matching dictionaries into a sequence.

Comment: Sure, conflicts should be solved according to different situations. Whether it's prioritized, random, or all relevant values should be returned. Here it's only for OP's case(if there can be only one ID in all dicts). Otherwise the logic of how to deal with valid results needs to be modified accordingly